# pdf is stretched on ipad

Tags: ipad, pdf, acrobat

I have a bit strange issue that I can't find solution.

I scan a document and scanner generates a PDF file. When I link to the file via web application and click on link all things look finn in browser but when I click on link and open file on iPad the PDF file (image) is stretched. I am almost sure that this have something to do how file is saved when generating PDF but I can't find anywhere in Acrobat how to fit file on screen normal instead of stretching it.

Pleas help if you have any ideas on what to do.

Comment: Could be something to do with pixel aspect ratio

Comment: I will read a bit more about PAR.

Comment: Did you find the answer?